# Installing rtl8188ru in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: drivers, alfa-wireless

i'm new to ubuntu/linux. After installing ubuntu 12.04 i'm not sure how to configure/install rtl8188ru wifi adapter. Anybody who can show me the easiest way to install the driver please.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Realtek Support site](http://goo.gl/V3JHy) and download the

> Linux Kernel 2.6.18~2.6.38 and Kernel 3.0.8

```
 $) unzip -x RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105.zip
 $) sudo sh install.sh
```

and you are done. Hope it helps